# Python - Is it possible from within an instantiated class function to view the 'self' of the calling method?

Tags: python, multithreading

```
class classB(object):
    def Bfunc1(self):
        "from here how can I access the 'self' of the calling class?"

class classA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._threadLocal = threading.local()

    def func1(self):
        self._threadLocal.x = 'stuff'
        cb = classB()
        cb.Bfunc1() <---
```

I am trying to see if I can retrieve certain data stored in the threadlocal from a classA through classB instance. My problem is that the 'self' reference is bounded to that class instantiated. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not want to give the data to classB at instantiate time? Or a reference to classA, or a reference to a shared structure... To answer more directly, having classB to access the self of classA kind of implies that classB should be declared inside classA as a static attribute.

Comment: Any reason you can't pass the `self` from `classA` as a parameter to `Bfunc1`?  Oh and BTW, your class definitions are wrong - I presume there is no hierarchy here and so you mean to inherit from `object`, not `self`.

Comment: *Is it possible to `inspect` the scope of the calling function and retrieve the variable `self` from the locals of that frame*: Yes, *Is it a good idea*: **no!** what if something else called `classB.Bfunc1()` and did not have a `self` instance in the calling scope?